# how to solve this scroll view error "ScrollView can host only one direct child"

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, scrollview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ECEFF1"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match parent"
    android:layout_height="match parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:background="#ED3733">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/homeScreenNavigation"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_menu_24" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="Dashboard"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="280dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="280dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="280dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="280dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start|left"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />


    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here "ScrollView can host only one direct child"
I don't know how to solve this error can someone help me to solve this problem
Thank you.................................,.....................................................................................................................................

Comment: As the error says scroll view should have only one direct child, but have a `LinearLayout` and then `NavigationView`. Either move the `NavigationView` inside the `LinearLayout` or out of the `ScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView and NestedScrollView can have only one child
you can use ConstraintLayout or other ViewGroup in ScrollView or NestedScrollView.

good luck.